# Connecting two tables and having count, distinct, and average of time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

First, I apologize if my question is not correctly organized.

I am trying to run an SQL Query in Java in order to return all the records of time difference. So to explain more:
I have two tables. Table A has the following structure:

```
Table `A` (
  `interaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `task_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_assessment` float DEFAULT NULL,
  )

 Table `B` (
  `task_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `task_type` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_due` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job_id` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

what I need is to get the count(distinct) from table A -and I do that using the `interaction_id`

and then get their times -using the task_time for each user and i use `"WHERE user_id='" + userId` (a java parameter).

After that I want to link Table A with Table B using `Job_id`
  so that I can get the difference date (in hour, so i used SELECT TIMEDIFF(Hour, A(task_time), B(task_due)).
  Finally, i need to get Average of the time difference.

I believe its a bit complicated when describing. But, I would appreciate your advanced help!

Thank you very much

Comment: Rather than posting your table structure, it might have been more helpful if you showed us minimal sample data from both tables, along with the output you expect.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen . I know, the problem is that i will have access to data next week, but trying thinking of this task.

Comment: If you don't have any real data, then fabricate some, you should have done this before posting.

Answer (score 0):

This query should gather the results that you are expecting:

```
select count(*) as countLines,
       avg(time_to_sec(timediff(A.task_time, B.task_due)) / 3600)
  from A
       inner join B on A.job_id = B.job_id
 where A.user_id = @userId
```

Comment: If there is a 1:1 relation between tables then there is no need.